# C# formatting CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I have some variables with strings in my program which I need to put to CSV file.

for example.

```
var1 = "abc";    
var2 = "bbb";    
var3 = "    
-vvv    
-xxx     
-zzz    
-ccc    
-ddd    
"; // Var 3 is a multiline string, need it to be put in one cell
```

CSV file:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3 (1 cell)
abc    bbb    -vvv
              -xxx
              -zzz
              -ccc
              -ddd
```

Then in next row: 
 var1(newVal) var2(newVal) var3(newVal)

Question is how to format CSV file that var x goes to colx and so on.

My code looks like this:

```
string getDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@getDir + "\\src");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
string str = "";
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  str = str + "," + file.Name;            
}

string lines="col1," + "col2," + "col3," + "col4 ," + "col5," + "col6," + "\n";

int ncheck = 1; 
int countFiles = d.GetFiles().Length; 

int vcheck = 0; 


    while (ncheck <= /*countFiles*/1) 
    {
        var getfile = str.Split(',')[ncheck];
        lines = lines + getfile;    
        while ( vcheck <= 4) 
        {
        string startSTR = "a1,a2,a3,a4,a5";
        var starts = startSTR.Split(',')[vcheck];

        string endSTR = "b1,b2,b3,b4,b5";
        var ends = endSTR.Split(',')[vcheck];


        string St = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(d + "\\" + getfile);

        int pFrom = St.IndexOf(starts) + starts.Length;
        if (St.IndexOf(starts) == -1 || St.IndexOf(ends) == -1) {pFrom=0;};
        int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(ends);
        if (St.IndexOf(starts) == -1 || St.IndexOf(ends) == -1) {pTo=pFrom+0;};


        String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
        if (St.IndexOf(starts) == -1 || St.IndexOf(ends) == -1) {result="Not found";};

        /*Console.WriteLine(starts);
        Console.WriteLine(result);          
        Console.WriteLine(ends);*/
        Console.WriteLine(lines);
        lines = lines + "," + result;
        Console.WriteLine(lines);
        vcheck++;
        }
        lines = lines + "\n";
        ncheck++;
        vcheck=0;
    }

System.IO.StreamWriter filetxt = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@getDir + "\\test.csv");
filetxt.WriteLine(lines);

filetxt.Close();
```

It is looking in src directory for txt files then searching for string and finally saving to CSV file. As I said before, I have problem with formatting document since one string has multiline which needs to be in one cell.

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: please post the code that you have so far to write the CSV file

Comment: I'm just using separators so far, but is there any better way to put some var in selected cell via c#?

Comment: "I'm just using separators so far," since I don't know **how** you do that, I personally am not able to say whether there is a better way

Comment: The question does seem pretty clear to me: "How do I properly escape multi-line CSV data?" It doesn't make sense to require code to answer that question.

Comment: Eric J, yes and no, because I also need to know if there is any way to put some variable in designated cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a comma in your string, or a newline, you must quote the string

Original: John Smith, Jr
Quoted: "John Smith, Jr"

If you have a quote in the string, escape it by double-quoting it

Original: John "Johnny" Smith
Quoted: John ""Johnny"" Smith

Combine both rules if you have commas/newlines and quotes in the string.

Original: John "Johnny" Smith, Jr
Quoted: "John ""Johnny"" Smith, Jr"

Here's an extension method I wrote that handles proper quoting. Use it like this:

var properlyQuoted = myString.CsvQuote();

```
    static public string CsvQuote(this string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        bool containsQuote = false;
        bool containsComma = false;
        bool containsNewline = false;
        bool containsCR = false;
        int len = text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len && (containsComma == false || containsQuote == false); i++)
        {
            char ch = text[i];
            if (ch == '"')
            {
                containsQuote = true;
            }
            else if (ch == ',')
            {
                containsComma = true;
            }
            else if (ch == '\r')
            {
                containsCR = true;
            }
            else if (ch == '\n')
            {
                containsNewline = true;
            }
        }

        bool mustQuote = containsComma || containsQuote || containsCR || containsNewline;

        if (containsQuote)
        {
            text = text.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
        }

        if (mustQuote)
        {
            return "\"" + text + "\"";  // Quote the cell and replace embedded quotes with double-quote
        }
        else
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to know how to put some variable's string to designated cell. For example var1 to B5 cell and so on.

Comment: You position in rows base on the line number of the text file. The fifth line of your output file is "5" when opened in Excel. The columns are made by outputting a comma in your file. Properly escaped commas don't count. `"One, eh?",Two,Three,Four,Five` would see the text "Two" in colun B (note that the comma in the first cell's data is escaped with quotes).

Comment: Yeah thank you I have fixed it, thank you for your answer it was helpful.